# React get attribute of a component instance

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a child component of a component. And I want to get and use its `placeholder` attribute. How can I do this?

I tried the following

```
<Namer>
    <input placeholder="firstname" type="text"/>
</Namer>
```

component code

```
function Namer({children}){
    return <div>
        {children.map(child=>{
            <>
                <label>{child.getAttribute("placeholder")}</label>
                {child}
            </>
        })}
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it in the `props`field of the component. so I used `child.props.placeholder`

```
children.map(child=>{
    <>
        <label>{child.props.placeholder}</label>
        {child}
    </>
})
```